# How to set indentation for javascript files in Idea IntelliJ 2016.3

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to set an indentation style for my javascript flies in IntelliJ following

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/code-style-javascript.html

But I don't see javascript under codestyle in my intelliJ. How to set the indentation for my js files? I am using Idea IntelliJ 2016.3

Comment: It should be there by default. Can you go through again & confirm??

Comment: No its not there. I have been looking for it since long. Not sure if its because of the IDE version I have

Comment: I'm using 2016.3.4, it is there. Can you pls tell me how you looked for?

Comment: You need IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate for JavaScript support: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you followed these steps as shown on the intelij support web site?

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206814405-Javascript-does-not-appear-under-code-style
This assuming you have the Ultimate edition of InteliJ

Answer (score 0):

You need ultimate version for JS support. Community version does not provide this functionality.